# "Tor unexpectedly exited."

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows

I have been using the TBB on two different computers (running win7 and win8) and have noticed that if I leave it running long enough that I always end up with an error message "Tor unexpectedly exited". This normally does not happen while I am using the TBB but in terms of how long it takes to exit it seems to vary, sometimes its like after 10 minutes of inactity sometimes overnight (and I don't know if it is actually due to "inactivity" it just doesn't seem to happen often while I am using TBB). I haven't found many posts about this on stackexchange or other places so it doesn't seem like a common problem, there was a few bug/mentions on the [tor blog](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/tor-browser-bundle-35-released) awhile back and [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/onions/comments/22aqwd/please_help_tor_unexpectedly_exited/) but that is it. I am running out of ideas and its a bit annoying (plus if I am not mistaken if I leave it on it helps the Tor network correct?)